# How to list rows with duplicate columns

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with the fields `id, name, birthday, clinic`:

```
id | name | birthday   | clinic
 1 | mary | 2020-01-01 | clin 1
 2 | mary | 2020-01-01 | clin 1
 3 | mary | 2020-01-01 | clin 2
 4 | john | 2021-01-01 | clin 1
 5 | pete | 2020-01-05 | clin 1
 6 | pete | 2020-01-05 | clin 2
 7 | pete | 2020-01-05 | clin 3
```

I want to get all records with `name, birthday` duplicate like:

```
id | name | birthday   | clinic
 1 | mary | 2020-01-01 | clin 1
 2 | mary | 2020-01-01 | clin 1
 3 | mary | 2020-01-01 | clin 2
 5 | pete | 2020-01-05 | clin 1
 6 | pete | 2020-01-05 | clin 2
 7 | pete | 2020-01-05 | clin 3
```

Mary and Pete have more than one record with same name and birthday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `COUNT()` as an analytical function, we can try:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name, birthday) cnt
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT id, name, birthday, clinic
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
select * from <table> where (name , birthday)  in (
    select name , birthday from <table> group by name, birthday having count(*)>1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an EXISTS condition:

```
select t1.*
from the_table t1
where exists (select *
              from the_table t2
              where t1.id <> t2.id
                and (t1.name, t1.birthday) = (t2.name, t2.birthday));
```